# Magento Tax issue on checkout using Rest API

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api, tax, totals

I am facing issue with tax on the checkout using magento 2 rest API. API always return tax amount 0 for all cart items. On web everything is working fine but getting issue with API.

My magento version is 2.3.1

Magento Rest API
`rest/V1/carts/mine/totals`

Comment: you can try this one /V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/collect-totals

Comment: Is this API working for registered customer also?